# Ubuntu 20.04.2 only boots on recovery mode, graphic card issue

Tags: boot, drivers, graphics

I know there are already dozens of this same question, and I've tried several fixes suggested in the other questions, with no results.

I can only boot in recovery mode, which is typically an issue with graphic card drivers. My computer used to boot normally. Issues started months ago, but until now I could fix it by rebooting several times until it worked.

`lspci | grep "VGA"`

gives

`00:02.0 VGA compatible controller: Intel Corporation UHD Graphics 620 (Whiskey Lake) (rev 02)`

The graphical interface for additional drivers gives me "no additional drivers available"

My OS version is 20.04.2 but this problem started months ago and has followed me through several versions. My desktop environment is XFCE if it makes any difference.

Thanks in advance for any help.

Answer (score 1):

You can use this hack it half worked for me:

I have the same problem that Fluffy_Alpaca:
I could not boot my computer because of a freeze of the screen at startup. By the way, the problem is the same for other guys ([Ubuntu 20.04 LTS freezing at boot/startup](https://askubuntu.com/questions/1353538/ubuntu-20-04-lts-freezing-at-boot-startup), [Ubuntu freezing time to time](https://askubuntu.com/questions/977153/ubuntu-freezing-time-to-time)) in this forum but no solution are sufficiently generic to be used.

Apparently, it is because some graphical drivers are not loaded. I tried this fix: https://itsfoss.com/fix-ubuntu-freezing/ which is based on adding `modenoset` in the GRUP config (`/etc/default/grub`).

My computer is booting now but the problem is my second monitor is not anymore recognized. So I guess the loading of the driver is bad eventually?

Here is my configuration:

Dell Latitude 7300

Release 20.04.3 LTS (Focal Fossa) 64-bit

Kernel Linux 5.11.0-40-generic x86_64

```
$ lspci | grep VGA
00:02.0 VGA compatible controller: Intel Corporation UHD Graphics 620 (Whiskey Lake) (rev 02)
```

It is NOT about NVIDIA graphical driver.

Thanks for helping!

Comment: https://itsfoss.com/fix-ubuntu-freezing/ worked for me.